# Equivalente em português para o termo "hardcoded"

Tags: significado, tradução

Gostaria de saber se existe um equivalente em português para o termo "hardcoded", tomado em sua acepção original, ou seja, um valor estático, imutável.

Comment: eu traduziria para valor fixo.

Comment: Não creio que exista uma boa tradução direta, especialmente uma que cubra usos como "xxx is hardcoded in our brains", mas algo que poderia funcionar em alguns contextos é "fixo/fixado no código".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta do Lucas Samuel está tecnicamente correta, porém creio que nunca utilizei o termo "Embutido" para me referir à um código `hard-coded` nos meus anos de programação no trabalho e faculdade...

Acredito que a grande maioria dos programadores usam o termo em inglês mesmo:

> O código tem diversos trechos **hard-code(hard-coded)**, então será necessário refatorar tais partes.

Agora, já ouvi alguns termos em português serem usados para significar a mesma coisa:

> Como era algo urgente, eu escrevi um **código fixo**. Assim que eu tiver tempo, irei reescrevê-lo.

Pessoalmente, nunca ouvi o termo `código engessado` como foi escrito nos comentários, mas não estranharia muito caso ouvisse. Porém (Pessoalmente) eu inicialmente pensaria em um código mal escrito, com uma lógica ruim, e não necessariamente em algo hard-coded.

PT-Br(Região Sul)

Answer (score 4):

*Hard-coded* é um termo utilizado na computação para alguma coisa que foi incluída diretamente no código fonte ([leia isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895803/12114971) e [isso](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/hard-coded) para mais detalhes).

Com base nisso, pode-se dizer que *hard-coded* se refere a [algo que foi construído de forma fixa](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/16934/hardcode), que só poderá ser alterado se, na computação, o código fonte for modificado ou se o objeto no qual esse "algo" foi introduzido for reconstruído.

Existem alguns adjetivos no português para caracterizar algo assim, como: fixo, constante, inalterável, determinado etc. Porém, existe um adjetivo em específico que, para mim, define melhor o que *hard-coded* expressa: embutido.

Uma das definições encontradas no dicionário de [Oxford Language](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-pt/) para o verbo embutir é:

> *bitransitivo*
> **construir ou incluir como parte integrante e, por vezes, inseparável.**
> "e. o microfone no gravador"

A partir disso, podemos interpretar o adjetivo **embutido** como algo que foi "incluído como parte integrante" e tornou-se inseparável.

Essa definição também se encaixa em outros contextos, como por exemplo:

1. "A ideia de que o jovem deve crescer, amadurecer e buscar constantemente o sucesso, mesmo que isso o reprima, está embutida na sociedade";
2. "Poucos entendem que a depressão necessita de acompanhamento médico, porque o significado de depressão está embutido na mente das pessoas como "frescura, falta de vontade ou autocomiseração", e não como uma desordem neurofisiológica";
3. "Esse conceito do professor como o detentor de toda verdade em sala de aula é embutido na cabeça dos alunos, de forma que eles não procurem criticar o que é apresentado".

Em todos os exemplos, **embutir** passou a ideia de algo que foi construído e solidificado, de forma que apenas uma desconstrução do velho sentido e uma construção de um sentido totalmente novo pode alterar isso, ou seja, esses conceitos foram incluídos diretamente no "código-fonte" da sociedade, e apenas alterando esse código-fonte poderemos alterar o sentido dado a essas coisas. ;)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site. *Embutido* foi também o que me veio à cabeça. Entretanto, a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_r%C3%ADgida) dá *codificação rígida* como equivalente a *hardcoding*. Mas *embuti os dados no programa* rola melhor que *codifiquei rigidamente os dados no programa*. Não faço ideia que terminologia usam os programadores de língua portuguesa. Possívelmente usam *hardcoding* :)

Comment: Obrigado, @jacinto. Eu sou programador, e usamos *hard-coded* mesmo, hahaha.

Comment: @Jacinto, os programadores não costumam traduzir termos. Nem hard-coded, como diz muito bem o Lucas, nem outros: [string](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadeia_de_caracteres), [cache](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache), [VOIP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOIP), etc.

Comment: @ANeves, foi isso logo que eu suspeitei no meu primeiro comentário. Eu já em tempos programei umas coisitas (Visual Basic), e pus uma base de dados inteira (umas 200 linhas x 10 colunas) hardcoded no programa! Já não me lembro como fiz, mas imagino que tenha escrito um programa auxiliar para ler os dados no excel e e incorporá-los no código.

Comment: Sou programador e quando não digo que algo está _hardcoded_ digo que está _engessado_ no código. É uma tradução possível.

Comment: Embora a resposata do Lucas seja bem abrangente, creio que minha pergunta foi mal formulada. O que queria saber, no final das contas, era qual termo os programadores brasileiros empregam e, pelo visto, usam o termo em inglês mesmo, assim como ocorre com os termos string, array (por vezes já ouvi a forma "vetor"), cache, void, cookie, etc.